# How to decompile a .dll file created in VS.net

Tags: c#, dll

I need to decompile a dll file created in VS.net.

Is there any tool available to do this?

Or Can I have some code to do this?

Please help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Edit 2: I now use [DotPeek from Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). Its ability to decompile as I need to while debugging is amazing.

Edit: [Now that Reflector is no longer a free tool](http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=13011), a newer tool [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) is under development.

[ILDASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(VS.80).aspx) is your friend if you don't want to use other tools.

Answer (score 9):

Check out [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

Answer (score 8):

I tried .NET Reflector and wasn't fully happy of the quality of decompiled code. Then I came across [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) and I must say it's way better then Reflector. I had to make only one small adjustement and decompiled code works as it should after compiling it in Visual Studio. I really recommend this decompiler especially it's completely free of charge.

Answer (score 5):

RedGate has a good tool and it **was** free:  [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)

Or you could use MS's ILDAsm (also free)

Answer (score 4):

Jet Brains [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) .net decompiler is awesome. also it is free to use

Answer (score 2):

With Reflector check the [file disassembler plugin](http://www.codeplex.com/reflectoraddins) too if you want to extract source.