# how to get source code from dll in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I have an assembly which is not strong-named. I have no source code for it.

I now need to recover the source code . Is there a way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decompile a .dll file created in VS.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503943/how-to-decompile-a-dll-file-created-in-vs-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use decompiler such as [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) or [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/).

Be aware of the fact that code is decompiled using IL code that resides in .NET assembly it may be different from the original code used when compiling the assembly.

Comment: thanks for the answer , i use the framword Docx .. et i want to recever his source code, to make update to my needs

Comment: In that case your first step should be contacting library author and permission for such modifications since they may violate license.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend RedGate [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/). You can try 14 days trial version.

Answer (score 0):

At work we used to use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/), until we learned that [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) is free. It serves us well.