# how to edit or see the source code for dll files

Tags: windows, dll

I have a DLL file for old game(age of empires)
I just want to edit that file or see the source code.
I tried reflector toll and some others, but without any result

so, 1- how can I edit or see  that DLL file??
    2- can I know In what language  that file was written?

Comment: If you want to ruin your weekend you could use `objdump`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It's sort of difficult. I mean you can look at the file with a *hex* editor, but it's not going to look nice. However, you can use 3<sup>rd</sup>-party tools in order to get as much info you can about the *.dll*:

   - [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) - useful to get the *.dll*s that your *.dll* depends on (and the functions that it need from there), exported functions, .... The bad thing is that last version is from 2006. A more actual replacement (written in *.NET*): [[GitHub]: lucasg/Dependencies - Dependencies - An open-source modern Dependency Walker](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)
   - [[HeavenTools]: PE.Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/overview.htm) - a nice tool (I'm not saying it's the best) that lists lots of info about the dll (sections, resources, ...) and it also has a disassembler (this reverse engineers the *.dll* and displays it in the form of assembly code). If you understand the assembly code you can then modify it (by modifying the corresponding bytes in your *.dll*), but that's for experts only. The problem is that it only handles *32bit* (*x86*) *.dll*s, and the latest version is from 2009 :(
   - [[MS.Docs]: DUMPBIN Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference) - part of *VStudio*. Displays (read only) various information
   - For *.dll*s written in *.NET*, check [[SO]: How to decompile a .dll file created in VS.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1503943/4788546)
2. Most likely it was written in *C*. The tools I listed can tell you more. You can also look with a text viewer at the *.dll*, inside it there might be references to source files (among all those unreadable symbols)

If the *.dll* has dependencies in form of *msvcr###(d).dll* (**#** sign is a placeholder for a digit) or *vcruntime###(d).dll*, then it's *C*, if it also has *msvcp###(d).dll*, then it's *C++* (created with *VStudio*).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to this:

For .net dlls an incredible program has arisen, made by JetBrains, called [DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) which greatly simplifies decompilation of **.net** dlls.