# How to call a WCF service with incomplete service definition

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to use a service created by somebody else. I have only the service dll. But the instructions provided to me are not complete. This is an example how to use the service but they missed the instantiation of the variable criteria. How can I figure out what type is the variable? . If possible, I prefer to solve the issue without decompiling the dll.

```
public static void GetData()
{
    //ServiceReference1.ServicesClient client = null; 
    try
    {
        criteria.Settings = new CheckCall.CriteriaSettings();
        CheckCall.Criteria criteria1 = new CheckCall.Criteria();
        criteria1.Settings = new CheckCall.CriteriaSettings();
        criteria1.AsgnType = CheckcallAssignTypeEnum.Driver;
        criteria1.TractorNumber = "Tractor1";
        criteria.Expressions = new List<CheckCall.CriteriaExpression>();
        criteria.Expressions.Add(new CheckCall.CriteriaExpression
        {
            Conjuction = CriteriaSetting.ConjuctionEnum.OrOp,
            Criteria = criteria1
        });
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What variable are you trying to find out the type?
If you only have the DLL and you want to see the underlying code, use a tool like dotpeek (https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to decompile the DLL

Comment: You can use Intellisense to see what types the parameters to different objects are. Hopefully they added documenting XML. Otherwise, you'll have to tell us where you're having problems, and what you're trying to instantiate. If their code isn't showing it, then we can't know what is missing from incomplete code either.

Comment: The variable name is criteria from : criteria.Settings = new CheckCall.CriteriaSettings();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decompile a .dll file created in VS.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503943/how-to-decompile-a-dll-file-created-in-vs-net)

Comment: If you are trying to get the definition of the service types, can you not just request the WSDL by putting ?WSDL to the end of the URL and put it in a browser

Comment: Please post the full error you are receiving as well.  It might be useful for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use JetBrains .Net decompiler - dotPeek.(https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)

Decompile the dll, then add the decompiled project to your solution and debug it. The only problem is wether you will receive a project that can be built after decompilation

If the decompilation is not an option/project has errors after decompilation - you can see the contents of the .dll via Object Browser. Find the .dll in the References, right click on it and choose "View in Object Browser". You will see the namespaces, classes and their methods of the .dll. Enter any of the property names of criteria object (Settings or Expressions) and Object Browser will filter everything out

Comment: Also Reflcetor by Red Gate can do the trick. If I remember it right they have got 14 days fully functional trial.

Comment: I prefer to solve the issue without decompiling the dll. If possible.

Comment: It might be a bit harder then. The only way is to get information from object browser. Find the dll in the references, right click on it and choose View in Object Browser, there you can navigate through the classes and namespaces of the dll

Comment: @Lio .net dll-s are not really machine code but IL language and you do not have to decompile them to look what the do if you understand IL code. But tools that papadoble151 and I propose can revers IL back to C# that way you can see implementation of them in more readable form.